# Disabling gore in Bioshock Infinite

Tags: bioshock-infinite

How can one disable, or at least tone down, the gore in Bioshock Infinite?

Answer (score 3):

No I'm afraid you can't. There is no such option in any of the menus, not even in the PC version. I searched around a bit, but for this game this isn't an option.

Also, if you read some [articles](http://venturebeat.com/2013/03/19/bioshock-infinites-combat-teaser-reveals-the-violent-action-you-can-expect-in-columbia/) you'll understand why. Just a small excerpt:

> The thing is — and this is possibly a spoiler — you’ll use your face-ripping, flesh-melting, eye-pecking weapons and powers to take out white supremacists. That’s game violence put to good use.

Comment: You'll use those powers on far, far more people than just white supremacists.

Comment: That's an excerpt from an article, used just to describe the "violent violence" in BS:I. The "white supremacists" was not the cardinal point here

Comment: Well. Looks like I'm not going for the execution achievement then. I got nauseous the first time I saw one and have refused to perform another ever since.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can't tone down or disable the gore/violence. At least on consoles.